# jQuery - Create an "Image Link" that belongs to a certain <div> class

Tags: jquery, image, html

I'd like to create an image element and assign/wrap it in a  class using jQuery. The image has to also act as a link i.e when the user clicks on it, the specified website should open. The following sample code creates an image element that points to Google's site. How can assign this element to a specified  class?

```
$('<img />').attr({'src':src})
.appendTo($('<a />').attr({href:'http://www.google.com'}).appendTo($('#targetLocation')));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var img    = $('<img />', {src:src, 'class':'imgClass'}),
    anchor = $('<a />'  , {href:'http://www.google.com'}),
    div    = $('<div />', {'class':'myClass'});

div.append( anchor.append(img) ).appendTo( $('#targetLocation') );
```

ends up with

```
<div id="targetLocation">
    <div class="myClass">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">
           <img src="whatever" class="imgClass" />
        <a/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you're doing it the right way, you should'nt use strings when you can use actual bonafied objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create and append with a variable?

```
var imgElement = "<a href='www.yourlink'><img class="your class" src="your src"/></a>";
$("#targetLocation").append(imgElement);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just build all the html as a string and call

```
var theHtmlString = 
    "<a href="http://google">" +
    "  <img src="whatever"></img>" +
    "</a>";
$('#targetLocation').append(theHtmlString);
```

Though that will also add this HTML to what is in the target location element and you might want to replace that element:

```
$('#targetLocation').html(theHtmlString);
```